# Client callback view state error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, callback

I am actually doing a search function by using client callback method. When the user starts typing, the GridView will give the result immediately. However now I got a problem. How can I display the result which user is selected?

Here is my coding:

```
List<Student> _student = new List<Student>();
private string _Callback;
partial class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CertificationDate { get; set; }
    public string ImageID { get; set; }

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _student.Add(new Student() { ID = 1, Name = "Ravi", CertificationDate = DateTime.Now, ImageID = "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_EBZOpH5YsH0/TV7DBZr44lI/AAAAAAAAApE/G0fRAUZmKR8/s800/ChromeIssue.png" });
    _student.Add(new Student() { ID = 2, Name = "TestUser", CertificationDate = DateTime.Now });
    String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,"arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
    String callbackScript= "function CallServer(arg, context)" +"{ " + cbReference + ";}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackScript, true);
}

 public string GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return _Callback;
    }

    public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
        {
            var Query = from p in _student
                        where p.Name.StartsWith(eventArgument, true, null)
                        orderby p.ID

                        select p;

            GridView1.DataSource = Query;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                GridView1.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
                _Callback = sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }


    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//?? Error occur here
        this.Label1.Text = this.GridView1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

My front end:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtUserName").keyup(function (event) {

            CallServer($(this).val(), "");
        });

    });

    function ReceiveServerData(rValue) {
        document.getElementById("ResultsSpan").innerHTML = rValue;

    }

 </script>
</head>

<input type="text" id="txtUserName" />
<div id="ResultsSpan">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID ">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'  ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

When I click the select button it give me this error **The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.**

How can I select the name or id, then the label will show the result also?